# OpenAPI specification File of HERE Routing API v8 (8.27.0) not valid

Tags: here-api, openapi, here-routing

I tried to use the OpenAPI Service Ref in Visual Studio 2019 to import the HERE Routing API Specification file into my Solution. But this didn't work. (obscure error code -1) As I tried to figure it out, I used a couple of other API tools, and found out that the reference on line 272 seemed wrogly formatted.

I changed this:

*LineString: "../shared/common.yaml#/components/schemas/LineString"* to *LineString: "#/components/schemas/LineString"*

The file is now imported and the classes are created. But now I am also having build errors because class Price isn't defined...

I have a feeling that this yaml file has a few hickups ;)
Hope you guys get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The development team is looking at this issue and I will keep updated here.

***Update***: This issue has been addressed and worked on with priority by the development team. So far the OpenAOI Spec doesn't support code generating.

Comment: The YAML file issue was fixed in production.